# Using async await with setImmediate

Tags: node.js

I want to know the how to use setImmediate with async await and handle errors properly. I have written following code. But I am not sure it is adhering to the best practices.

There is a route in my express app

```
router.get('/parseinvoice', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const parsedInvoiceResponse = await userhelper.getParseInVoiceList();
        res.json({parsedInvoiceResponse})
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({});
    }
});
```

The userhelper class code

```
 var userhelper = {};
const fs = require('fs'),
      path = require('path'),    
      filePath = path.join(__dirname, './input_user_story_12.txt');

const { promisify } = require('util')
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);



userhelper.getParseInVoiceList = async function() {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            setImmediate(async function() {
                try {
                    const contents = await readFile(filePath, 'UTF-8');
                    resolve(contents);
                } catch (error) {
                    reject(error);
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
           reject(error); 
        }
    });
}


module.exports = userhelper;
```

Although I am getting the response. I am not sure about the **setImmediate part**, whether the multiple *try catch* are required. Is there any neat way to write the below code?.

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    setImmediate(async ()=>{
        var res = await readFile(filePath, 'UTF-8');
    })
} catch(err) {
}
```

2.

```
await setImmediate(()=>{
       var res = await readFile(filePath, 'UTF-8');
}).catch(){}
```

3.

```
try {
    await setImmediate(()=>{
       await readFile(filePath, 'UTF-8');
    }).catch(){}
} catch() {
}
```

4. should return result into res

```
const res = await setImmediate(()=>{
     return readFile(filePath, 'UTF-8');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not just using?

```
userhelper.getParseInVoiceList = async function() {
    return await readFile(filePath, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: I want to execute that code in next iteration of event loop. Therefore I am using it.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on `@Dan D.`'s answer, you can `await` the resolution of an asynchronous `setImmediate` prior to calling the asynchronous promisified `readFile`, but I am not sure why you would need to do this without more context.

```
userhelper.getParseInVoiceList = async function() {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setImmediate(() => resolve()));
    return await readFile(filePath, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Node 15, you can use [`timersPromises.setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timerspromisessetimmediatevalue-options):

```
​import { readFile } from "fs/promises";
import { setImmediate as sleepImmediate } from "timers/promises";

userhelper.getParseInVoiceList = async function() {
  await sleepImmediate();
  return await readFile(filePath, 'UTF-8');
}
```